# Can I cable this relay to my regulator?

Tags: relay

I have to control a temperature, with a 3.5 kW under 230 V AC resistor.

I have a regulator with this OUT : 4 A / 240 V AC.

I found [this](http://datasheet.octopart.com/RSB1A160P7S-Schneider-Electric-datasheet-14413007.pdf) relay to commute my circuit.

My question is : can I use it ?
It's 4 kVA and my circuit is only resistive. The coil resistance is 38500 Ohms, so I =...0,006 A ? But as specified in the doc' : "rated operational current" is 8 A or 16 A (changes according to the cabling, isn't ?).

That's my problem. What amount of ampers will the relay take from the regulator ? Is it 6e-3 A or 8, 16 A ? Does this "rated operational current" refer to the current in the command or power side ?

Thx, and sorry for my english (not my native-tongue...),

F36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your required load current is 3500W/230V = 15A. The normally-open (NO) contact is rated at 16A, so it is not exceeding the ratings. You don't need to (shouldn't) use the normally-closed (NC) contact, which is only rated at 8A.

The coil current is minimal, and well within the 4A capability of your temperature controller (aka regulator).

However, I strongly suggest you look at the life of this component. You are operating right at the maximum current, so you can expect it to last no longer than the 70,000 rated operations. At a 20 second cycle time it will **wear out** in a couple of weeks if operated 24/7 (continuously). Maybe that's acceptable for you, but it should be considered.

[image]

Comment: Yeap, I forgot to mention the 15 A part (that's why I was wondering about this 8 A NC too).
The tool won't be used 24/7, a few hours per months. Thank's for your quick answer :)